# Python and Android apps

Tags: android, python

I've been using Python for about a year now and would love to start writing some Android apps using Python.

I've been researching both Kivy and SL4A and I'm a little confused about something.

When you develop an Android app using Python and one of the above, does the user of the Android device need to download anything special in order to run?  Or is it all transparent to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user doesn't have to install anything, it's all transparent to the user, but keep in mind that the `.apk` will contain a full python installation, and thus you simply can't write apps that take less than about 10MB.

On Google Play there are some sample applications made with kivy, for example there is a [touchtracer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.touchtracer) app that you may download to see if kivy would work on your device.

kivy requires OpenGL ES 2.0 for graphics, which is not always supported, even though most modern smartphones support it(I have a chinese B63M and kivy works fine with it).
The OpenGL ES 2.0 support is provided in Android 2.2+.

You may find other information about packaging for Android in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353523/510937) answer.